# Variables in the selected mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I would like to declare a variable (@mediate_price) in a SELECT MYSQL and then use the variable in the same SELECT.

It's possible?

For example:

```
SELECT 
Id,
prezzo,
@prezzo_medio:=AVG(prezzo) AS ‘Prezzo medio’,
@prezzo_medio * 2 AS ‘Doppio prezzo’

FROM 
Listino;
```

Obviously the example is theoretical.

Comment: You might *want* to do this, but the MySQL documentation explicitly warns against assigning a value to a variable and then using it in another expression.  So, don't do this.  Either repeat the expression or use a CTE or subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply